# .SVG on html site for logo and icon

Tags: html, css, svg

Is that right if use .SVG image for Logo and icons in design ? if its right how should do use it to support all browser ?

If use .SVG image on html its not support on internet explorer how can fix it ?

```html
<img src="example.svg" alt="SVG">
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

take a look here: http://caniuse.com/#feat=svg

You see the IE8 doesn't support svg but you have the option to do a trick (https://j.eremy.net/inline-svg-with-ie8-fallback-support/).

to your question "is that right if use ..."

The most important reason for me is the following:

> SVG offers a way to do full resolution graphical elements, no matter
>   what size screen, what zoom level, or what resolution your user's
>   device has.

Comment: https://j.eremy.net/inline-svg-with-ie8-fallback-support 
this link is failed to open

Comment: For me the Link is working, sorry. Please google for svg fallback

Answer (score 1):

Correct way would look more like [this](http://css-tricks.com/svg-fallbacks/):

```
<svg width="96" height="96">
  <image xlink:href="svg.svg" src="svg.png" width="96" height="96" />
</svg>
```

[And SVG is supported in IE since IE 9.](http://caniuse.com/#feat=svg)

Comment: @pavol with css can change image color ?

Comment: CSS inside the image file can, CSS on the page can't

Comment: @RobertLongson could you explain more ?

Comment: @RobertLongson do you have any example ?

Comment: Ask another question and I'll try to answer. Comments aren't really a good way of working.